# How to correctly convert AVAudioCompressedBuffer into Data and back

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I have an `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` instance that gets correctly decoded and played by my `AVAudioEngine`.

The problem is that after converting it to `Data` and then back to `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` it is no longer playable and throws a `kAudioCodecBadDataError`.

This is how I'm currently managing the conversion to and from `Data`:

```swift
// Convert AVAudioCompressedBuffer to Data
let capacity = Int(compressedBuffer.byteLength)
let compressedBufferPointer = compressedBuffer.data.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: capacity)
var compressedBytes: [UInt8] = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: capacity)
        compressedBufferPointer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: capacity) { sourceBytes in
compressedBytes.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
                $0.baseAddress!.initialize(from: sourceBytes, count: capacity)
           }
       }
        
let data = Data(compressedBytes)
```

```swift
// Convert Data to AVAudioCompressedBuffer
let compressedBuffer: AVAudioCompressedBuffer = AVAudioCompressedBuffer.init(format: format, packetCapacity: packetCapacity, maximumPacketSize: maximumPacketSize)
compressedBuffer.byteLength = byteLength
compressedBuffer.packetCount = packetCount
data.withUnsafeBytes {
            compressedBuffer.data.copyMemory(from: $0.baseAddress!, byteCount: byteLength)
        }
let buffer = compressedBuffer
```

The values for all of the buffer attributes (`format, packetCapacity, maximumPacketSize, byteLength, packetCount, byteLength`) are the same on both ends of the conversion.

Comment: You should use `byteLength` instead of `byteCapacity` when going from `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` -> `Data`

Comment: I changed it but the error is still the same.

Comment: It was a guess! Can you update the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, for some reason, converting `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` that way fails to include the buffer's `packetDescriptions`. These are stored as a C-Style array of `AudioStreamPacketDescriptions` structs in the buffer. By creating a `Codable` struct (`PacketDescription`) and mapping the descriptions objects separately the reassembled buffer worked as expected.

```swift
var packetDescriptions = [PacketDescription]()
        
for index in 0..<compressedBuffer.packetCount {
   if let packetDescription = compressedBuffer.packetDescriptions?[Int(index)] {
           packetDescriptions.append(
                        .init(mStartOffset: packetDescription.mStartOffset,
                              mVariableFramesInPacket: packetDescription.mVariableFramesInPacket,
                              mDataByteSize: packetDescription.mDataByteSize))
            }
        }
```

```swift
packetDescriptions?.enumerated().forEach { index, element in
       compressedBuffer.packetDescriptions?[index] = AudioStreamPacketDescription(mStartOffset: element.mStartOffset!,
                                                                                       mVariableFramesInPacket: element.mVariableFramesInPacket!,
                                                                                       mDataByteSize: element.mDataByteSize!)
        }
```